# SpriteKit: Passing variable from GameViewController to GameScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, segue

I created a menu in Storyboard that passes some information through a segue to GameViewController. Ideally, I could use that segue to pass the information directly to GameScene.swift where I need it, but I'm not sure that's an option since a scene is just a view and not a view controller. So, I pass the information to the GameViewController and that works great. But now, how to I get it to GameScene.swift?

**Segue from menu to GameViewController**

```
func passToGame(game: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGameSegue", sender: game)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? GameViewController {
            if let item = sender as? String {
                destinationVC.gameInfo = item
            }
        }
    }
```

**GameViewController**

```
    class GameViewController: UIViewController {

        var gameInfo: String? //This works great - now how do I get it to GameScene.swift?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others `SKNode`, `SKScene` have an istance property called [userData](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483121-userdata), you could use this dictionary to store whatever you want before to present the scene (this example come from the "*Hello World*" Sprite-kit template):

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var gameInfo: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                // Present the scene
                scene.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
                scene.userData?.setObject(gameInfo ?? "", forKey: "gameInfo" as NSCopying)
                view.presentScene(scene)
            } 
            ...
```

To retrieve the value from the `GameScene` you can simply do:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    if let gameInfo = self.userData?.value(forKey: "gameInfo") {
                print("gameInfo is :\(gameInfo)")
    }
    ...
```

Comment: only thing I would change, is check to see if userdata does not exist first before creating it, like this `if userData == nil { userData = ["gameInfo" : gameInfo]} else {userData["gameInfo"] = gameInfo}`

Comment: I didn't know about userData - thank you. Is it true that you can't segue directly to an SKScene from UIKit?

Comment: @squarehippo10 Segue objects are instances of the UIStoryboardSegue class to transition from one view controller to another, a scene is presented by a [SKView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview). As you can see they are two totally different entities..