# swift: how to save controller data for use by GameKit GameController?

Tags: ios, swift, controller, gamekit

I have an initial view controller that gets the players name from input and transitions to the GameKit GameController with a segue.

I tried this prepare segue method in my **LaunchViewController**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print(usernameTextField.text) // returns users name correctly
        if let navigationVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let myViewController = navigationVC.topViewController as? GameViewController{
            myViewController.playername = usernameTextField.text
        }
    }
```

and in my **GameController** i try:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

     var playername:String?

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                // Load 'GameScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
                // including entities and graphs.
                if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

                    // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
                    if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {

                        // Copy gameplay related content over to the scene
                        sceneNode.entities = scene.entities
                        sceneNode.graphs = scene.graphs

                        print(self.playername) //returns nil
                        sceneNode.userData?.setValue(self.playername, forKey: "playername")
                        print(sceneNode.userData)

     // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                    sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                    // Present the scene
                    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                        view.presentScene(sceneNode)

                        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                        view.showsFPS = true
                        view.showsNodeCount = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In my game scene i try to access the userData from the scene.

however the playername variable is returning nil in the GameController.

Whats the correct way to set a value to the member var across controllers?

Comment: Are you sure the segue's destination should be a navigation controller? I believe you only need to do `if let myViewController = segue.destination as? GameViewController { ... }`. I think `playerName` is `nil` because the `if let ... {}` in the `prepare(...)` function is evaluating to false (the segue's destination is not a `UINavigationController`) so the `playerName` is not being set in `GameViewController`.

Comment: yes that did the trick thank you. i overlooked that i was going straight to game controller without the navigation controller. i copied that function from an example.

Comment: however now the `GameScene: SKNode` is loaded in `GameScene.sceneDidLoad()` before the `GameController: UIViewController` sets the `SKNode`'s `rootNode.userData` in `GameController.viewDidLoad()` causing the views user data in `scenedidload()` to be nil. It is correct in the controller.
Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I've basically tried passing it to the scene like this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239709/spritekit-passing-variable-from-gameviewcontroller-to-gamescene` but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Could you maybe move the logic that uses `userData` to the scene's `didMove(to:)` function? I didn't realize `sceneDidLoad()` can be called before the view is presented, but I'm fairly certain that `didMove(to:)` is not called until after the scene is presented, so the `userData` should be initialized from the `GameViewController` by then.